# How can I configure my DHCP server to distribute IP routes?

Tags: linux, dhcp, route, ipcop

I have a DHCP server (Linux, IPCop, dnsmasq) running on my default gateway server 192.168.0.1. I have a VPN endpoint on another server in the network (192.168.0.4). Is it possible to configure the DHCP server so it sends not only the default gateway but also routing information for the VPN (192.168.1.*) to DHCP clients when they request an IP address? The DHCP clients run Windows and Linux.

I tried to find something in the official documentation (http://www.ipcop.org/2.0.0/en/admin/html/custom-dnsmasq-local.html) but failed. The existence of [RFC3442](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442) indicates that it might be possible somehow.

Comment: http://jcape.name/2009/07/17/distributing-static-routes-with-dhcp/

Comment: From the link it is not obvious to me what to put in `dnsmasq.local`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done by adding the following lines to `dhcpd.conf`:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of integer 8;
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 24, 192, 168, 1, 192, 168, 0, 4;
option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes 24, 192, 168, 1, 192, 168, 0, 4;
```

This distributes a route entry for network 192.168.1.0/24 using the gateway 192.168.0.4.

The meaning of the bytes is (in brackets the value from the example above):

```
WW, D1, D2, D3, R1, R2, R3, R4
WW      = destination network mask width (24)
D1..D3  = destination network address (192.168.1.*)
R1..R4  = router address (192.168.0.4)
```

Note: The number of `D1..DN` bytes varies depending on the network mask. See [RFC3442](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442) for details.

Comment: confused - pretty sure that the OP specifies dnsmasq as the server

Comment: pretty extensive explanation on how it works: https://serverfault.com/a/575936/155358

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the RFC 3442 option is a bit unusual. This is a representation of [blerontin's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/640866/63361) in a more graphical way, which some might find easier to understand.

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of integer 8;
option      ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of integer 8;

# Route                             to     192.168.1.0/24 through 192.168.0.4;
#                                       ┌───────────────┘
#                                       |   |   |  |   
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 24, 192,168,1,             192,168,0,4;
option      ms-classless-static-routes 24, 192,168,1,             192,168,0,4;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define multiple static routes....

If you specify the option multiple times.. only 1 (probably the last) will apply.

Instead, just concatenate the entries..
eg

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes X, X,X,X,X, X,X,X,X;
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes Y, Y,Y,Y,Y, Y,Y,Y,Y;
```

but

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes X, X,X,X,X, X,X,X,X, Y, Y,Y,Y,Y, Y,Y,Y,Y;
```