# How can I configure systemd.network DHCP server to distribute IP routes?

Tags: linux, dhcp, systemd

From [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/640565/how-can-i-configure-my-dhcp-server-to-distribute-ip-routes) I understand that I can use DHCP to distribute classfull routes. How to do it with the DHCP server embedded in systemd.network (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual [www.freedesktop.org/...](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BDHCPServer%5D%20Section%20Options) shows only a handful of options and nothing that indicates support for such more advanced DHCP server options.